# AWS Organization API with postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, cloud, postmessage, aws-organizations

I am new to the postman and trying to get the ListAccounts from AWS Organizations API. Below is the screenshot and error I have to follow:

[image]

Error:

```
{
    "__type": "InvalidInputException",
    "Message": "You provided a value that does not match the required pattern.",
    "Reason": "INVALID_PATTERN"
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with the complex request signing requirements of aws api calls?

Comment: Not much, it will be helpful if guided. I am new to it

Answer (score 0):

Authentication of most API requests is straightforward - you attach an `Authorization` header with Oauth or JWT.   This kind of auth is a simple fit for postman which has easy ways to pass Authorization headers.

One obvious flaw is that the authentication token is a secret that is sent along with the request.  That means anyone that can access the request, knows the secret as well as you do.

AWS uses a different mechanism in which the secret is not attached to the payload.  Instead, the secret is used to sign the request with HMAC.  The secret isn't sent along with the payload, but anyone who already has the secret (AWS generated it in the first place) can verify that the payload was signed with the appropriate secret.  In this scheme, intercepting a request payload does not divulge the secret necessary to authenticate novel requests.

[This blog post](https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-generate-aws-signature-with-postman/) describes how postman can be made to authenticate API requests with [amazon's Signature v4 method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html).  It looks possible.

My advice would be to stick to the AWS provided SDKs for one of your preferred languages.  They offer high quality SDKs for python ("boto3" is a very common AWS go-to for crafting API requests), Ruby, Go, Java, JavaScript ... pretty much every language has one.  The SDKs do a great job of representing the underlying AWS APIs, along with helping you manage error conditions, authentication, resolving endpoints for regions, pagination, etc.